# when to use custom deleter for std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I am using C++ std::shared_ptr and wanted to know if there is any other use for custom deleter apart from overriding the delete ptr. Or what are the scenario in which it is recommended to provide custom delter for a shared_ptr

Comment: It's usually used with libraries that return opaque pointers or otherwise require special deletion functions - like `Foo* CreateFoo()`/`void DeleteFoo(Foo*)`.

Answer (score 4):

Not all memory is allocated with `new` and memory is not the only kind of resource that needs to be released, e.g.

```
std::shared_ptr<FILE> open_file(const std::String& path, const std::String& mode)
{
  if (FILE* f = :fopen(path.c_str(), mode.c_str()))
    return std::shared_ptr<FILE>(f, ::fclose);
  throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open file");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to spell out a deleter explicitly. But the class needs to have the feature to allow various kinds of type erasure, such as constructing a `shared_ptr<T>` from any `unique_ptr<T, D>`, and a `shared_ptr<void>` from any `shared_ptr<T>`. The default deleters are there when you first create the object, and they get propagated along all those conversions.

And you can sometimes use a custom deleter for other kinds of [resource management](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h), though most times a `unique_ptr` is probably more appropriate and sufficient for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom deleter when `delete` will not do what you want. Consider different scenarios:

You acquire the memory from a pool and use placement new to create the object. Calling `delete` on an object not created with `new` will be undefined behavior, so you need to plug a deleter that will use the appropriate memory pool. This applies to memory acquired with `malloc` and released with `free`, for example, or any other type of memory allocator. This also applies to memory acquired from different heaps.

The resource is not even memory at all, but a file descriptor, database connection, etc. The deleter needs to release the resource when there are not references to that resource, but releasing the resource does not involve calling `delete`, but some other operation.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there are two goals achieved with the deleters.

1. Give you a way to override `delete ptr;` (as you said).
2. Make it impossible to use shared_ptr and unique_ptr with forward declaration classes.

Comment: You don't need a custom deleter to use `shared_ptr` with incomplete types, the type only needs to be complete when you first initialize a `shared_ptr` (which is usually the case, because you've just allocated the object at that point, so the type must be complete)